# How to change this javascript code to jQuery specially the string concatination part

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert this javascript into jQuery but am unable to do so

//JavaScript

```
var d_Inp = document.getElementById("dollar-input");
var dsign = document.getElementById("dollar-sign");
d_Inp.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  let len = d_Inp.value.length;

  dsign.style.right = `${len + 3}ch`;
});
```

//jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dollar-input").keyup(function(){
        let len = $("#dollar-input").val.length;
        $("label").css("right","len+3+ch");
    })
 })
```

I think I am wrong somewhere `$("label").css("right","len + 3ch");` here

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you need to use `val()` to get the value of input

```
 let len = $("#dollar-input").val().length
```

Then while adding css you directly added string instead of using value from the len

```
$("label").css("right",len+3+"ch");
```

Comment: $("label").css("right","len + 3ch"); can you help me to correct this too

Comment: You can use same like you did in JavaScript like ``${len + 3}ch`` to concat the ch to lengh